# How to add values to an multiindexed column dataframe

Tags: pandas

My dataframe is

```
    a                       b
    1           2           1           2  
0   0.281045    0.975469    -0.538213   -0.180008
1   0.128696    1.875480    0.247637    -0.047927
```

I want to insert the matrix to `(a,3), (b, 3)`

```
[[1, 1],
[1, 1]]
```

```
    a                              b
    1           2           3      1            2           3
0   0.281045    0.975469    1.     -0.538213    -0.180008   1.
1   0.128696    1.875480    1.     0.247637     -0.047922   1.
```

It seems like there is no decent way to add value to the multiindex dataframe, Here is the code that I tried:

````
df[:,:,3] = [[1, 1],
             [1, 1]]```
But it didn't work...
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` and then append to data by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 1],[1, 1]]) 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, 
                   index=df.index, 
                   columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0], [3]]))

df = df.join(df1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
          a                      b             
          1         2  3         1         2  3
0  0.281045  0.975469  1 -0.538213 -0.180008  1
1  0.128696  1.875480  1  0.247637 -0.047927  1
```

Comment: so what's ur technique for reading multiindexes? i found a code on stack overflow that seemed to work, but doesnt seem robust

Comment: @sammywemmy - I change data in text editor, not very nice technique :(